# Сихронизация завершения работы потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность, синхронизация, .net-4.0

Работаю в C# 4.0.

Сценарий - запускаю N (значение известно только в момент начала запуска потоков) потоков - каждый выполняет свою задачу и должен возвращать результат. Результаты собираются в предназначенный для этого массив. 
Проблема появилась откуда и не ждал - сообщение приложению/потоку об окончании работы ВСЕХ потоков - пробовал использовать событийные инструменты ([Manual/Auto]ResetEvent) но проблему не смог решить. 
Не подскажите возможное решение кроме использования

```
while(true) 
    {...}
```

?

Comment: В WinAPI есть WaitForMultipleObjects(); Посмотри как её можно использовать в шарпе.

Comment: @WhereColdWindsBlow: А как это поможет?

Comment: На каждый поток по событию. При завершении потока, выставляешь событие в сигнальное состояние. Когда все будут выставлены, функция WaitForMultipleObjects() "разморозит" вызвавший её поток.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, нет - я не хочу отменять выполнение потоков а именно дождаться их полного выполнения.
На мой вопрос как ни странно ответил [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6(v=vs.110).aspx)

`WaitHandle.WaitAll(manualEvents);`

где manualEvents список ожидаемых событий

Comment: Просто все привыкли к TPL и к Task.WaitAll (Task.WhenAll для async/await) для решения подобной задачи где все это упаковано в относительно удобную обертку

Comment: Я указал версию фреймворка... Увы TPL тут никак...

Comment: Мне сложно судить, потому что есть версия языка и дот.нет (и  по идее вы указали именно ее), но в .net именно с 4й версии и появился TPL и вроде бы даже есть порт поддержки TPL на 3.5. Так что похоже, что TPL у вас таки есть или же вы хотели указать .NET 2/3.5

Answer (score 2):

Штатное средство отмены чего бы то ни было — [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.100).aspx). При этом нужно понимать, что потоки нельзя остановить «силой» снаружи, они должны остановиться сами, получив сигнал.

Итого:

- Вы заводите в главной программе `CancellationTokenSource`.
- Каждому потоку раздаёте `CancellationToken`.
- Код в потоке либо окружаете конструкцией try/catch, ловите `OperationCanceledException` и время от времени выполняете `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` на токене (а также передаёте токен в вызываемые функции, которые его поддерживают), либо время от времени проверяете `IsCancellationRequested` на токене и завершаете поток вручную.
- В главной программе, когда нужно завершение потоков, вызываете `Cancel` на `CancellationTokenSource`, и дожидаетесь окончания всех потоков через `Join`.

Всё!